GitHub Loading Issue - Site Not Fully Rendering
I'm experiencing an issue with GitHub where the site is not fully loading. Specifically, some content is missing, and certain elements fail to render properly. It's taking an extremely long time to load the entire page, and even then, only the raw HTML loads; CSS and images are still missing. The loading spinner keeps circling indefinitely, and even after an hour, the page still hasn't fully loaded. This makes using GitHub extremely difficult. The issue is occurring specifically with GitHub; other sites are loading fine. I've tried different browsers like Edge and Firefox, but the problem persists. I've been facing this issue for the past 3-4 days, and it occurs on both my laptop and desktop.
To resolve the issue, I’ve tried the following:

Clearing browser cache and cookies: I expected this to clear any corrupt data, but it didn’t fix the problem.
Disabling browser extensions: I thought an extension might be interfering, but disabling them didn’t help.
Using different browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Edge): I expected the issue to be browser-specific, but it persisted across all browsers.
Restarting my computer: I hoped a fresh start would clear any temporary issues, but no luck.
Checking GitHub's status page: I wanted to see if there were any known issues, but everything was reported as operational.

Despite these attempts, the problem persists. I'm looking for additional troubleshooting steps or insights into what might be causing this issue. Has anyone else encountered this, and if so, how did you resolve it?
update: raised a ticket to github support.
update: I wanted to update everyone on the situation. After trying all the suggestions provided, it became clear that the issue was related to my network provider. When I connected through my mobile hotspot, GitHub loaded without any issues. However, when I switched back to my Wi-Fi, the site would only work if it was already open—reopening the tab caused the problem to resurface.
update: I contacted my network provider, and after some investigation, they managed to fix the issue. Unfortunately, they couldn’t explain the exact cause, as the backend team handled it and didn't share the details. It appears to have been an issue on their end, specific to GitHub, since other websites worked fine. Thankfully, the problem is now resolved.
